# Robust way to avoid the "Office.js has not fully loaded" error in a ReactJS project

Tags: reactjs, ms-office, office-js, dvajs

We develop Excel add-ins. From time to time, we observe this `Error: Office.js has not fully loaded. Your app must call "Office.onReady()" as part of it's loading sequence (or set the "Office.initialize" function). If your app has this functionality, try reloading this page.` It did not seem very blocking. However, now we realize that when this happens in Mac for Excel, the taskpane becomes a blank page. Users have to reload the page again to not see this error and load well the page.

So we would like to find a robust way to avoid this error.

Our add-ins are built with Reactjs and [dva](https://github.com/dvajs/dva), which is a framework based on redux, redux-saga and react-router. Here is `frontend/src/index.tsx`:

```
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';
import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';
import dva from 'dva';
import router from './router';
import AuthModel from './models/auth';
import SubscribtionModel from './models/subscription';
import AppModel from './models/app';
import SpreadsheetModel from './models/spreadsheet';
import UsageModel from './models/usage';
import SettingsModel from './models/settings';
import { initializeIcons } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Icons';

initializeIcons();

const app = dva();

app.model(AuthModel);
app.model(SubscribtionModel)
app.model(AppModel);
app.model(SpreadsheetModel);
app.model(UsageModel);
app.model(SettingsModel);

app.router(router);

app.start('#root');
```

Here is `src/router.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { routerRedux, Switch, Route } from 'dva/router';
import Layout from './layouts';
import LoginPage from './components/LoginPage';
import Welcome from './components/welcome';
import SocialLoginSuccess from './components/socialLoginSuccess';
import { AwaitPromiseThenRender } from './components/AwaitPromiseThenRender';

const { ConnectedRouter } = routerRedux;
function RouterConfig({ history }: any) {
  //@ts-ignore
  return (
    <AwaitPromiseThenRender
      //@ts-ignore
      promise={typeof window.__$$notInOffice !== "undefined" ? Promise.resolve(true) : Office.onReady()}
    >
      <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
        <Layout>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/sign">
              <LoginPage />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/home">
              <Welcome />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/app">
              <App />
            </Route>
            ... ...
            ... ...
        </Layout>
      </ConnectedRouter>
    </AwaitPromiseThenRender>
  );
}

export default RouterConfig;
```

Here is `src/components/AwaitPromiseThenRender/index.tsx`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

interface IProps {
  promise: Promise<any>;
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

interface IState {
  promiseHasResolved: boolean;
}

export class AwaitPromiseThenRender extends Component<IProps> {
  state: IState = { promiseHasResolved: false };
  constructor(props: IProps) {
    super(props);
    props.promise
      .then(() => this.setState({ promiseHasResolved: true }))
      .catch(e => console.log("invokeGlobalErrorHandler(e)"))
  }

  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;
    const { promiseHasResolved } = this.state;

    return promiseHasResolved ? children : null;
  }
}
```

Does anyone know how to amend our existing code to definitely avoid the `Office.js has not fully loaded` error?

Comment: What's the meaning of the condition passed to the `promise` prop of `AwaitPromiseThenRender`? If you say, the error happens intermittently, this means the condition sometimes returns `Promise.resolve(true)` and renders the children? Is it in this case your error from Office.js occurs?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend following the pattern that the yo office React template uses. Don't render until Office.onReady() completes. To see the entire template code, see [Install the Yeoman generator — Yo Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/overview/set-up-your-dev-environment?tabs=yeomangenerator#install-the-yeoman-generator--yo-office). Run 'yo office' and then choose the React template to generate the project.

```js
let isOfficeInitialized = false;

const title = "Contoso Task Pane Add-in";

const render = (Component) => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <AppContainer>
      <ThemeProvider>
        <Component title={title} isOfficeInitialized={isOfficeInitialized} />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </AppContainer>,
    document.getElementById("container")
  );
};

/* Render application after Office initializes */
Office.onReady(() => {
  isOfficeInitialized = true;
  render(App);
});
```

Comment: Thank you. But I have already used the dva framework, see `frontend/src/index.tsx`. Do you know how to modify my existing code?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the dva framework, but basically you want to avoid calling any Office.js APIs until Office.onReady is complete. Most frameworks have a startup sequence or something of an entry point like render(App), so you'd use whatever that is for dva. If it is multiple entry points you can call Office.onReady more than once wherever you need it to ensure initialization before you call any Office.js APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Basically seems like error tells you there is a flow in which you try to do something before office.js has fully loaded.
Your logic seems fine, but I would suspect two things in the code:
I would suspect a few things:

- Maybe the issue is not in the rendering phase, but in the initialization phase. Where you call app.model. If that is the case I would try to initialize in onReady

```
Office.onReady(()=>{
   app.model(AuthModel);
   app.model(SubscribtionModel)
   app.model(AppModel);
   app.model(SpreadsheetModel);
   app.model(UsageModel);
   app.model(SettingsModel);

   app.router(router);

   app.start('#root');
})
```

- If `window.__$$notInOffice` is true/false/null you will not call Office.onReady() at all. Could that be the problematic flow? In such case simply pass Office.onReady()

```
 return (
    <AwaitPromiseThenRender
      promise={Office.onReady()}
    >
```

Answer (score -1):

Ensure Office.js Initialization: You should initialize Office.js properly before rendering any content in your add-in. The Office.onReady() function is designed to notify your add-in when Office.js is fully loaded and ready for interaction. In your current code, it seems you're already using Office.onReady(), but it's important to make sure that it's called before any other code that depends on Office.js.

Restructure the Routing: Your routing code should be placed inside the Office.onReady() callback to ensure that your app doesn't render any content until Office.js is ready. This will help prevent the blank task pane issue. Here's how you can modify your code to achieve this:

**In your src/router.tsx file:**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { routerRedux, Switch, Route } from 'dva/router';
import Layout from './layouts';
import LoginPage from './components/LoginPage';
import Welcome from './components/welcome';
import App from './components/App'; // Make sure to import your App component
import { AwaitPromiseThenRender } from './components/AwaitPromiseThenRender';

const { ConnectedRouter } = routerRedux;

function RouterConfig({ history }: any) {
  return (
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <Layout>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/sign">
            <LoginPage />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/home">
            <Welcome />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/app">
            <App />
          </Route>
          {/* ... Other routes */}
        </Switch>
      </Layout>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  );
}

export default RouterConfig;
```

**In your src/index.tsx file:**

```js
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';
import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';
import dva from 'dva';
import router from './router';
import AuthModel from './models/auth';
import SubscribtionModel from './models/subscription';
import AppModel from './models/app';
import SpreadsheetModel from './models/spreadsheet';
import UsageModel from './models/usage';
import SettingsModel from './models/settings';
import { initializeIcons } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Icons';

initializeIcons();

Office.onReady(() => {
  const app = dva();

  app.model(AuthModel);
  app.model(SubscribtionModel);
  app.model(AppModel);
  app.model(SpreadsheetModel);
  app.model(UsageModel);
  app.model(SettingsModel);

  app.router(router);

  app.start('#root');
});
```

By restructuring your code in this way, your app's routing and rendering logic will only kick in once Office.js is fully loaded, ensuring a smooth and error-free experience for your users.